# mule java component throwing IllegalArgumentException

Tags: mule, mule-component

I am running Mule 3.6.2 in STS 3.6.4. I am trying to use a simple Java Component.

```
public class MyComponent implements Callable {

   public MyComponent() {
    super();
   }

   @Override
   public Object onCall(MuleEventContext eventContext) throws Exception {
    return eventContext.getMessage().getPayload();
   }
}
```

and a Simple flow in Input phase of Batch component....

```
<flow name="MainFlow>
    <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="${app.host}" port="${app.port}" path="test" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <cxf:jaxws-service serviceClass="example.sampleservice.TempService" doc:name="CXF"/>
    <component class="com.temp.MyComponent" doc:name="Java"/>
    <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
 </flow>
```

At the java component line, I get a

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: object is not an instance of declaring class
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.7.0_75]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[?:1.7.0_75]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.7.0_75]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[?:1.7.0_75]
at org.mule.model.resolvers.AbstractEntryPointResolver.invokeMethod(AbstractEntryPointResolver.java:148) ~[mule-core-3.6.2.jar:3.6.2]
at org.mule.model.resolvers.MethodHeaderPropertyEntryPointResolver.invoke(MethodHeaderPropertyEntryPointResolver.java:109) ~[mule-core-3.6.2.jar:3.6.2]
at org.mule.model.resolvers.DefaultEntryPointResolverSet.invoke(DefaultEntryPointResolverSet.java:36) ~[mule-core-3.6.2.jar:3.6.2]
at org.mule.component.DefaultComponentLifecycleAdapter.invoke(DefaultComponentLifecycleAdapter.java:339) ~[mule-core-3.6.2.jar:3.6.2]
at org.mule.component.AbstractJavaComponent.invokeComponentInstance(AbstractJavaComponent.java:82) ~[mule-core-3.6.2.jar:3.6.2]
at org.mule.component.AbstractJavaComponent.doInvoke(AbstractJavaComponent.java:73) ~[mule-core-3.6.2.jar:3.6.2]
at org.mule.component.AbstractComponent.invokeInternal(AbstractComponent.java:125) ~[mule-core-3.6.2.jar:3.6.2]
at org.mule.component.AbstractComponent.access$000(AbstractComponent.java:59) ~[mule-core-3.6.2.jar:3.6.2]
at org.mule.component.AbstractComponent$1$1.process(AbstractComponent.java:241) ~[mule-core-3.6.2.jar:3.6.2]
at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:24) ~[mule-core-3.6.2.jar:3.6.2]
at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:58) ~[mule-core-3.6.2.jar:3.6.2]
at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44) ~[mule-core-3.6.2.jar:3.6.2]
at org.mule.processor.chain.DefaultMessageProcessorChain.doProcess(DefaultMessageProcessorChain.java:94) ~[mule-core-3.6.2.jar:3.6.2]
at org.mule.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain.process(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:69) ~[mule-core-3.6.2.jar:3.6.2]
at org.mule.processor.chain.InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.doProcess(InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.java:50) ~[mule-core-3.6.2.jar:3.6.2]
at org.mule.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain.process(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:69) ~[mule-core-3.6.2.jar:3.6.2]
at org.mule.processor.chain.InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.access$001(InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.java:22) ~[mule-core-3.6.2.jar:3.6.2]
at org.mule.processor.chain.InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper$1.process(InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.java:66) ~[mule-core-3.6.2.jar:3.6.2]
at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:24) ~[mule-core-3.6.2.jar:3.6.2]
at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:58) ~[mule-core-3.6.2.jar:3.6.2]
at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44) ~[mule-core-3.6.2.jar:3.6.2]
at org.mule.processor.chain.InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.process(InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.java:61) ~[mule-core-3.6.2.jar:3.6.2]
at org.mule.component.AbstractComponent.process(AbstractComponent.java:159) ~[mule-core-3.6.2.jar:3.6.2]
at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:24) ~[mule-core-3.6.2.jar:3.6.2]
at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:58) ~[mule-core-3.6.2.jar:3.6.2]
at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44) ~[mule-core-3.6.2.jar:3.6.2]
at org.mule.processor.chain.DefaultMessageProcessorChain.doProcess(DefaultMessageProcessorChain.java:94) ~[mule-core-3.6.2.jar:3.6.2]
at org.mule.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain.process(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:69) ~[mule-core-3.6.2.jar:3.6.2]
at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:24) ~[mule-core-3.6.2.jar:3.6.2]
at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44) ~[mule-core-3.6.2.jar:3.6.2]
at org.mule.processor.AbstractInterceptingMessageProcessorBase.processNext(AbstractInterceptingMessageProcessorBase.java:102) ~[mule-core-3.6.2.jar:3.6.2]
at org.mule.module.cxf.CxfInboundMessageProcessor.processNext(CxfInboundMessageProcessor.java:389) ~[mule-module-cxf-3.6.2.jar:3.6.2]
at org.mule.module.cxf.MuleInvoker$1.process(MuleInvoker.java:88) ~[mule-module-cxf-3.6.2.jar:3.6.2]
at org.mule.module.cxf.MuleInvoker$1.process(MuleInvoker.java:84) ~[mule-module-cxf-3.6.2.jar:3.6.2]
at org.mule.execution.ExecuteCallbackInterceptor.execute(ExecuteCallbackInterceptor.java:16) ~[mule-core-3.6.2.jar:3.6.2]
at org.mule.execution.HandleExceptionInterceptor.execute(HandleExceptionInterceptor.java:30) ~[mule-core-3.6.2.jar:3.6.2]
at org.mule.execution.HandleExceptionInterceptor.execute(HandleExceptionInterceptor.java:14) ~[mule-core-3.6.2.jar:3.6.2]
at org.mule.execution.BeginAndResolveTransactionInterceptor.execute(BeginAndResolveTransactionInterceptor.java:54) ~[mule-core-3.6.2.jar:3.6.2]
at org.mule.execution.SuspendXaTransactionInterceptor.execute(SuspendXaTransactionInterceptor.java:50) ~[mule-core-3.6.2.jar:3.6.2]
at org.mule.execution.RethrowExceptionInterceptor.execute(RethrowExceptionInterceptor.java:28) ~[mule-core-3.6.2.jar:3.6.2]
at org.mule.execution.RethrowExceptionInterceptor.execute(RethrowExceptionInterceptor.java:13) ~[mule-core-3.6.2.jar:3.6.2]
at org.mule.execution.ErrorHandlingExecutionTemplate.execute(ErrorHandlingExecutionTemplate.java:59) ~[mule-core-3.6.2.jar:3.6.2]
at org.mule.module.cxf.MuleInvoker.invoke(MuleInvoker.java:83) ~[mule-module-cxf-3.6.2.jar:3.6.2]
```

I know what the exception means, but unable to understand in this context.

Comment: Could you please post the complete stacktrace?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create simple java component then instead of implementing callable,
try with **mule specific** annotations.

```
public myComponent(){
   super();
}
public String myComponent(@payload String myPayload) {
  <!--your operation goes here--> 
 system.out.println("created my simple java component!"); 
 return myPayload;
```

}

Cheers!

Comment: That would work, except, I need access to the MuleEventContext  :(

Comment: What do you want to get out of eventcontext?

Comment: @jeet you can use **@Groovy("eventContext")** as one method parameter to get out something out of MuleEventContext.